# In game development, what aspects to consider when choosing a 32-bit architecture over a 64-bit architecture?

Tags: c++, directx11, win32

I was developing a graphics engine from scratch using Direct3D11 and some APIs, but I stumbled in a situation where it would beneficial to me to use a certain library, but it's binaries are only available on 32 bits.

I've changed my engine to 32 bits and didn't see much difference in terms of speed, would it be troublesome to use it on 32 bits? What other surprises lie around the corner?

Comment: Quite the opposite. Some processor extensions allow operations for two 32-bit numbers simultaneously. Also, smaller variables mean less memory usage, which is particularly relevant in game graphics. Most graphics engines and graphics API use 16 bit variants whenever possible to reduce memory overhead and improve processing speed... Google `half4`. Older processors required multiple steps to perform operations on 64-bit numbers, but that's far less common nowadays. In game dev, use the smallest you can get away with. One downside: If you *need* 64 bit maths, it'll be much slower in a 32 bit app

Comment: Good to know it! But about the downside... I am using DirectXMath to do lots of math calculations on my engine, some of the variables are XMVECTOR, XMMATRIX, XMFLOAT4X4. If I'm not mistaken these are 64 bytes, right? Then does it mean my engine is going to have troubles with these?

Comment: Ops, I just remember now that XMVECTOR is only 16 bytes.

Comment: If the number of bits you're using matters, you've likely got other problems.

Comment: @Almo strange comment. Things like this always matter for performance. Bitness, compiler settings, structure layout, instruction in the CPU cache... (I seem to remember reading some analysis of a program that got xx% slower after adding a new unused function, because of how it moved other code around in the cache)

Comment: @Rafael Ferreira Exactly... You'll find most of those data types are 16 bit for exactly this reason. Eg nVidia still talking about their 8 and 16 bit processing: https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/mixed-precision-programming-cuda-8/ `The new NVIDIA Tesla P100, powered by the GP100 GPU, can perform FP16 arithmetic at twice the throughput of FP32`

Comment: @Basic this looks like it would be worth writing up as an answer that can be upvoted and accepted. It would also be worthwhile to mention that in a 32-bit app, the amount of memory you can address is more limited than with 64 bit.

Comment: @Basic How does the 64-bit vs 32-bit influences this? AFAIK, the only differences in sizes are the pointer related types (and std::size_t). Libraries that require `float` will still require `float`, not `double`.

Comment: @user253751 This looks like an interesting candidate for an answer! I'm looking forward to read an expanded version of your comment!

Comment: Ok, thank you all for your answers.

Comment: @user253751 Not a strange comment. A comment born of 21 years in professional game development.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most obvious thing to consider is that using a 32-bit architecture for your executable allows you to address about ~4gb of RAM on Windows while using a 64-bit architecture allows the program to address 128gb+. This means that you can put much more stuff into RAM before experiencing issues.

A situation where this *could* **¤** be an issue is loading your 3d models and their textures into Video RAM. For instance, the machine's graphics card allows to load 8gb of data (the nVidia DLL will manage this just fine even using a 32-bit app), and you want to take advantage of it, so you'll create nice models with big, highly detailed textures, which will end up taking 6gb of memory.

With a 64-bit architecture, you would simply have to load everything into RAM, then have the graphics API load it into Video RAM. But with a 32-bit architecture, you'll need to cut down your loading process into smaller pieces: load a chunk of data into RAM, send it to VRAM, unload it from RAM, then repeat with the other chunks, until everything is done.

---

¤ Note that this will often depend on how you do things, what you need in your game, and how you've arranged your architecture; I used a framework where this was an issue: we loaded an image from disk into RAM, but there was no check telling us that memory couldn't be assigned, so the rest of the code tried to upload a "null" image into VRAM. We either had strange bugs, at strange places, or some parts of the models just appeared black.

Comment: See [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dxtecharts/sixty-four-bit-programming-for-game-developers) and [Gamasutra](https://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/132003/sponsored_feature_ram_vram_and_.php). For Windows PC, it's fine to ship a 32-bit EXE if your memory requirements are modest, but if you plan to ship on Xbox some day you need a 64-bit EXE. In general, make sure your code is portable as much as possible. I'd also be a little concerned about a library that's not available as 64-bit--is it old? Is it maybe unsupported these days?